# Is the Fibonacci sequence the only increasing strong divisibility sequence such that u_0=0 and u_1=1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci sequence has several interesting properties, among which the following ones :

- $ F_{0}=0 $  and  $ F_{1}=1 $
- $ (F_n) $ is a strong divisibility sequence
- $ (F_n) $ is an increasing sequence.

Are there any other integer sequences fulfilling all those properties ?

Comment: what about the sequence $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots$ ?

Comment: Well, I should have said "non trivial sequence of integers"...

Comment: $0,1,4,9,16,\ldots$ ?

Comment: How about *any* exponential sequence $a^n$, where we simply have $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$ and $a_{n\geq 2} = a^n$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$. It's not alone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any recurrence relation of the form

$$F_0=0, F_1=1, \quad
F_n= F_{n-1}+k\cdot F_{n-2}$$

where $k$ is a positive integer. Fibonacci is the case with $k=1$.

Also, any sequence given by $\frac{p^k-1}{p-1}$ where $p,k$ are coprime.

Answer (score 2):

This article might be of interest to you:[https://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2014/750325/ ]. It specifically mentions a generalization of the Fibonacci sequence with $L_{n+1}=pL_{n}+qL_{n-1}$ and $gcd(p,q)=1$ called the Generalized Lucas Sequence. They also prove that it is a strong devisibility sequence and it is obviously increasing.